# Get the "extender" page in Jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Having some trouble finding this documented anywhere, if it does exist.
I have a "base.html" that is used in other pages in the form of "extends base.html".

I want to implement an if statement in "base.html" that only runs if it is used by "certain_page.html".

Obviously, I could set this page to use a different copy of base.html, but that seems counter to the goal - this exception might come up, rarely, on other pages.

So, does an "if caller certain_page.html" condition exist that I can implement in base.html?

Are there any alternative methods of doing this I'm not considering?

Comment: Maybe define a `{% block certain_page %}{% endblock %}` in base.html and only use that block in `certain_page`?

Comment: That would work, but it would have to be two blocks (one "base" and one "exception"), which defeats the purpose of avoiding having to rewrite this into every single template page. What I'm effectively trying to do is add certain classes to certain divs on specific pages. I'm guessing there's no way to directly do what I want (extender conditional)?